# How multi region is supported in Azure Service Fabric for state-full services?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

How **multi region** is supported in **Azure Service Fabric** for **state-full** services ?

I understand the multi-region support can be configured for **stateless services**, but how the **state full services** span across multi region

Comment: Do you want to span single stateful service partition to multiple regions or you are talking about having different partitions for different regions?

Comment: single stateful service partition to multiple regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not openly recomended, from the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions#can-i-create-a-cluster-that-spans-multiple-azure-regions-or-my-own-datacenters)

> **Can I create a cluster that spans multiple Azure regions or my own datacenters?**
>
> Yes.
>
> The core Service Fabric clustering technology can be used to combine
>   machines running anywhere in the world, so long as they have network
>   connectivity to each other. However, building and running such a
>   cluster can be complicated...

There are many challenges and limitations, like VNET does not span multiple regions, performance & latency.

On stateful services the challenge will be even higher, because the data must be replicated before it is considered 'commited', having to replicate data in multiple regions, adds a lot of latency and increase the risk of failures, it can also get affected by network speeds that won't be as fast as connectivity between zones of same region or within same datacenter. There is also the risk of placing the instances of your services(data) on placement groups that can be taken down at same time on different regions, even though they are different domains, they might be on same maintenance schedule.

Inside Azure, services based on SF like EventHub, are deployed as multiple clusters within same region spanning multiple zones. This already gives your cluster enough reliability in case of an entire zone failure, for a better reliability and durability, you could mirror your existing cluster as a failover in another region and do constant backups\restore to keep then in sync.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Is this something Azure Service Fabric team is going to provide in the future may be using Service Mesh ?

Comment: Today is already possible like explained above, but adds a complexity that requires expertise to manage, with Mesh, it would be more flexible, but still require a better planning on applications to avoid the issues described.